# android ImageButton set alpha in api 8

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, alpha

The problem is setAlpha is only available for api 11 and I'm using 8.
In the xml I have

```
android:background="@null"
```

because I dont want to show backgroud.
I only want to set the alpha in java file to show when the button can and cannot be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [`setAlpha(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29) since API level 1. Use that instead of `setAlpha(float)`. (Remember that `ImageButton` extends `ImageView`)

Comment: sorry this was a stupid question... when I used setAlpha(int) for some reason my eclips put a cross over it so I thought it didnt work but it does! Thank anyway :)

Comment: this is depricated right? but setAlpha float is only available in v11+

Comment: What should one put as an int parameter?What is the value for completely transparent and what is for completely opaque?

Comment: For API <11, is there any method to set the alpha value as a float within the code? I want to dim an ImageButton i.e. `myButton.setAlpha(0.2)`, not make it completely transparent. You can use a float value in the XML layout, so I'm hoping there is some sort of workaround.